# different result in java how can it be rectified

Tags: java, math

Simple calculation gives different result in java.

```
int a=5363/12*5;

out.println(a);// result is 2230
```

But actually result should be `2234.5`

How can this java result be rectified?

Comment: Integers are not Real numbers.  Doubles and Floats are.  Use the correct data type.

Comment: @mcfinnigan why others are down voting my question, what's their problem? by down voting they want to prove that they have the power to down vote

Comment: Given your answers below, it's probably also appropriate to link David Goldberg's paper as well.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @mcfinnigan: doubles and floats are not real numbers -- they are floating-point numbers.  Yes I am being pedantic, but one needs to be in this domain.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark granted, I wasn't pedantic enough =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The expression `5363/12*5` gives an integer result (in particular, the division is integer).
2. The variable `a` is of type `int` (integer).

To fix:

```
double a=5363.0/12*5;
out.println(a);
```

Note that in general you can't expect to get exact results when using floating-point arithmetic. The following is a very good read: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: thanks it is coming as 2234.5833333333335 but how to restrict it to 2235 ?

Comment: To get the solution without using `double` or `round`, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

5363, 12, and 5 are all being interpreted as ints. the calculation actually being performed here is:

```
5363/12 = 446.9… - truncated to the int value 446
446 * 5 = 2230
```

Try specifying a as a float, and indicate that the numbers in the calculation are also created as floats:

```
float a = 5363f/12f*5f
```

Answer (score 1):

Take `a` as double.

Taking a as int will round it to the integer.

Comment: result is coming as 2230.0 but it should be 2234.5

Answer (score 1):

Because your all the literal numbers in the right hand side are integers (e.g. 5363 as opposed to 5363.0) expression is being calculated using integer arithmetic semantics i.e. `/` does whole number division. Thus 5262/12 equals 446 and 446*5 equals 2230. Also your variable `a` is an `int` which can only ever hold an integer value.

To fix this you need to do two things. Change the type of `a` to a decimal type e.g. `float` or `double` b) have at least one of 5363 and 12 represented as a decimal type e.g.

```
double a= 5363.0/12.0*5
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using double you can re-order your expression.

Assuming 5363/12*5 = 5363*5/12 this will give you a closer answer.  You have commented you want to round the result so instead you have to add half the value you are dividing by.

```
int a = (5363 * 5 + /* for rounding */ 6) / 12;
System.out.println(a);
```

prints

```
2235
```

Answer (score 0):

An `int` is an Integer - nothing after the `.`.

You should be using

```
double a = 5363d/12*5;
```

Comment: @tom `5363d` tells the compiler to treat the value `5363` as a `double`, not an `int` as it would normally do.

Comment: yes any ways i am up voting your answer can you please up vote my question

Answer (score 0):

It seems it has some int/double rounding issue:

```
double a=((double)5363/12)*5;
System.out.println("VALUE: "+a);
```

Prints:

> VALUE: 2234.5833333333335

Edit: rounding the result to an integer value:

```
double a=((double)5363/12)*5;
long b=Math.round(a); //you can cast it to an int type if needed
System.out.println("ROUNDED: "+b);
```

Prints:

> ROUNDED: 2235

Comment: yes result is coming as 2234.5833333333335 but it should be 2234.5

Comment: @tom No it shouldn't, you can't change math!

Comment: somebody down voted your answer, can you please round it so that it will come as 2235?

Comment: @Marcelo yes i know i cannot change the math that's why you downvoted my question right?

Answer (score -1):

Use double 
double a =  5363/12*5;
System.out.println(a);

or 
cast the integer, to prevent loss or precision.

int a  = ((int) 5363/12*5);
System.out.println(a);